# Files.write and Files.readAllBytes changes byte[] input

Tags: java

I am writing a unit test and I am seeing the following which I don't understand. Any help is appreciated.

```
tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp", "file");
Files.write(tempFile.toPath(), expectedBytes);
byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(tempFile.toPath());
Assert.equals(b, expectedBytes); // failed
```

Comment: a byte array is only equal to itself. Not to any other byte array, even if the other array has the same bytes. The same goes for all arrays, by the way.

Comment: Try Assert.assertArrayEquals() instead (assuming JUnit here).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays do not support deep comparison with `equals`. Check if that `Assert` class has an `arrayEquals` method.

Comment: that works, thank you very much!